# How to get the curent UIEdgeInsetsMake?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uicollectionviewcell, uiedgeinsets

I have created collection view cell via storyBoard,for the 4 and 5 inch screen i have set the  UIEdgeInsetsMake as programatically,if the device is not 4 and 5,then my storyboard  UIEdgeInsetsMake have to set for that.

How to do it?

This is my code

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                        layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
        insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenSize.width;
    UIEdgeInsets insets= UIEdgeInsetsMake(?,?,?,?);//how to get the current edge insets.
    if(screenWidth==320)
    {
        UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,12,20,2);
        return insets;
    }
        return insets;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `contentInset` property.

Also, you're re-declaring the variable `insets` in your code. Consider changing to the following for simplicity:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
    insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width == 320)
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,12,20,2);
    }

    return collectionView.contentInset;

}
```

Comment: @Stone2 how to get the width and height bro via programatically ...\

Comment: @KishoreKumar Width and height of what?